# set_target_properties COMPILE_FLAGS also sets assembler flags, do not want

Tags: cmake

When I do this:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET_BASENAME_A} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "--std=c99" )
```

It sets the flag `--std=c99` in both compiler and assembler command lines.
The assembler does not recognize that flag so it fails.

I only want the flag to appear in the compiler command line, not the assembler.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCES_C} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${TARGET_C_FLAGS})
```

This appears to work, applying the flags only to those files in the SOURCES_C variable.

Comment: wow time flies.  Note the above will affect all source files, so to set target-specific flags it won't work.